# NSPopover and NSTableView cell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm looking for way attach NSPopover to cell of NSTableView.

```
showRelativeToRect:(NSRect)positioningRect ofView:(NSView *)positioningView preferredEdge:(NSRectEdge)preferredEdge;
```

The question how I can find `positioningRect` and `positioningView` for cell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answer is easy:
use `[tableview frameOfCellAtColumn:0 row:[tableview selectedRow]];` for `positioningRect` and `tableview` for `positioningView`